# Quarkus does not generate environment file definition in sam.jvm.yaml

Tags: quarkus

I am using quarkus with quarkus-amazon-lambda.
In the ./src/main/resources/application.properties I have following defined

```
quarkus.lambda.handler=mainHandler

aws.region.default=eu-central-1
aws.region=${AWS_REGION:${aws.region.default}}
```

And when I do "./gradlew clean build" it does not generate the required definition in "./build/sam.jvm.yaml"

So I need to manually add the missing definition of the environment variables to the .yaml:

```
  Resources:
    MyLambdaFunction:
      Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
      Properties:
        Handler: io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.QuarkusStreamHandler::handleRequest
        Runtime: java11
        CodeUri: function.zip
        MemorySize: 256
        Timeout: 15
        Policies: AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
        
   # ---this part is missing---
        Environment:
          Variables:
            AWS_REGION:
```

I cannot find where else I need to define the expected environment variables so that it will be generated.

Answer (score 0):

there are "quarkus.aws.*.region" properties for individual services, look for 'region' on https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config

If none match open a issue with a reproducer.